# Delete context files from android by its key pattern

Tags: android, file

I am deleting a file from my android application like this

```
public static Boolean deleteObject(Context context, String key) throws IOException,
      ClassNotFoundException {
      return context.deleteFile(key);
   }
```

But I want to delete a file with its key starting with the provided key.

For example: calling this function

```
deleteObject(this,"file")
```

Deletes file having this name "file-10-10-14"

Comment: No one is answering, At least please tell me is that even possible to do that or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the file list with

```
context.fileList();
```

then get the file name of the file you want to delete from the string array and delete that with the key.

Comment: wow I can iterate through and delete all files with that pattern thanks.